# indicator-netspeed alternative for kde

Tags: networking

Is there an alternative to [indicator-netspeed](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/indicator-netspeed-displays-network.html) on kubuntu? I want a widget that displays upload and download on the panel.

Comment: What version of KDE are you using?

Comment: @Wilf kubuntu 14.04!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by installing knemo:

```
sudo apt-get install knemo
```

then adding it to my startup applications (autostart)

It is the best netspeed!!

Answer (score 2):

I found this yesterday and I feel good about it.

1. Right click on desktop > add widget
2. click get new widget
3. Download new plasma widget
4. search for `netspeed` in the search box. Install it.
5. Drag the newly installed netspeed to your plasma panel.